# Django-oauth is sending and receiving data without access token in ionic app?

Tags: android, django, oauth, ionic-framework, django-authentication

I am using `Django-oauth-toolkit` for social authentication in ionic android app.

First i get token from social auth plugin then i send it to django. Django-oauth-toolkit generates user and send me access token and refresh token back. After that when i send `GET request for` user related data (without sending access token in header) then also django-oauth is accepting the request and sends me back userdata.

How is it possible ? Am i doing something wrong in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason.

It was happening due to

```
DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS
  'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
```

in Django Rest Framework.

This class allowed all the apis without access token.